# Share xDB data between two installations - possible?

Tags: xdb

We have two websites on separate physical installations with each there webservers, databases and mongodb.

Is it possible to have the two websites use the same mongodb and thereby leverage the same contact/user data?

Regards

Comment: More on an infrastructural plan, I tried to share the same Azure Cosmos DB for analytics and tracking on two instances. It resulted in **"Tracker is not initialized"** error. An instance was locking the access to the database and forbidding others to access.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We asked this question to Sitecore support a while ago as we had 2 instances with websites of the same company (one with sxa and one without).

We wanted to be able to use xDB without limitations, and asked if we could share Mongo to match contacts.

The answer:

> In order to have different goals, outcomes and so on you will have to
>   use different content databases on different environments. If the
>   analytics bases are the same, aggregation might work, but you will
>   definitely see incorrect data in reports, as the analytics definition
>   items are not shared.
>
> Best practice is either use same databases in all environments, or use
>   all different databases in different environments (which is better).

So if you have different databases, you should not use the same Mongo's. Which makes sense in a way, but can be a pity in some setups.

Comment: Have you considered using FXM on one of the sites, instead of the full-fledged xDB? Just an idea off the top of my head...

Comment: Yes, but if you have 2 fully running Sitecore sites you don't want to go that way.. Well, I didn't :) We are using personalization etc on both sites so we went for the safe solution.

Comment: Gatogordo - Thanks for the reply. "The safe solution" - what does that mean?
Did you manage to do personalization on both sites?

Comment: Yes, the "safe" solution was to use separated Mongo instances. So nothing shared - but that also means no shared data. Maybe when xConnect arrives we might see what we can achieve with that..